# Is it a bad backup strategy in Oracle to have only Level 0 backups and Archive Logs in between with no incremental?

Tags: oracle, backup

If you backup the database with a Level 0 every six hours, then do the archive logs in between, every 15 minutes perhaps, what benefit would I have to incorporating a differential backup?  Essentially, full backup only with archive logs x minutes.  Particularly cumulative.  Is it only because of disk space?

I have read this,

[Is it enough to have only full backup and transaction log backup only for a good backup plan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136438/is-it-enough-to-have-only-full-backup-and-transaction-log-backup-only-for-a-good)

But it did not help, as it includes a differential.

Edit:  I ask because I thought you had to have a full backup to use a differential in the first place.  So why not just have the full backup to begin with?

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't help"?  It explained the principles - and in this case, even though they were addressing MSSQL, the principles are the same.  If you understand the principles you should be able to judge for yourself if your proposed/present strategy is "bad".  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: If you can comfortably store multiple full backups, if the restore time is acceptable and the resources required while the backup is running is acceptable you can stick with this simple scheme. Simple is good.

Comment: @EdStevens In that question it mentioned differentials.  I'm wanting to know it without anything in between the full backup except archive logs.  Why is that "bad" or is it?  I want to be able to recover quickly, so I don't understand why I'd need anything else.  When you do a differential, and you do a restore, wouldn't you need the last full backup anyway?

Comment: @eckes Would my restore time be longer if I had differentials and archive logs?

Comment: @johnny depends on the change rate, but restoring multiple days of archivelogs can be slow. Basically you Restore eve4y change of an record compared to the endstate.

Comment: Bit basically a full backup done very often would result in the fastest restore time, so if this works for you do it.

Comment: @eckes You should put an answer.  I would mark it correct.  But I think you can't now.

Comment: Technically you don't _need_ anything but full bkup + archlogs, but for fastest recovery you don't want to rely solely on archlogs.  After restoration of db from full bkup, recovery will begin with any available inc-1 backups. When those are exhausted it will continue with archlogs but in general recovery from archlogs is slower than from inc bkups. In the end the only 'bad' strategy is one that fails to meet recovery requirements.  But some are less efficient than others.

Comment: That part about slower than inc. backups was key.  Thank you.  It was the missing piece.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have enterprise edition or standard edition? If you have enterprise edition you can create a block change file and do a true level 1 incremental backup. Doing a level 0 backup is a FULL backup. There is not reason for you to do a FULL backup every 6 hours. Most people do a FULL backup every day and possibly send the archive logs to more than one server. I do two level 0 backups per week and level 1 backups on the days when I am not doing a level 0 backup. If you are new to Oracle you may want to do a backup/recovery class. You should practice backup and recovery on development databases.

Comment: But why is it bad to do the full backup and archive logs?  That's what I don't get.

Comment: You don't need 4 full backups per day. You should probably specify the size of your database and the longest time that you can wait for a restore. It might also help to know what edition of Oracle you use, number of cores and amount of RAM. As others have stated, you do the backup so that you can recover if needed.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, you're asking the wrong question.

What are your Recovery Point and Recovery Time Objectives? 
(That is: how *quickly* do you need to get the database back after a critical failure and how much data are you prepared to *lose* in doing so?)

Get *those* answers nailed down (and that's not solely *your* decision, by the way; it needs to come from your Organisation) and *then* you can start worrying about how to *achieve* those objectives and, from that, the kinds of backups you're going to need.

Remember - you're implementing a *Recovery* Strategy; backups are just a way to deliver that.

After all:

*Backups* are a complete waste of time and effort ...   *until* you've completed a *Recovery* that uses them.

Answer (score 1):

The most important question is: Why are the backups done the way they are done? Are there special reasons for takeing full backups every six hours?

You can do - depending on your database edition - a lot of backup strategies. The best method depends on your Environment. How big is your DB? Do you want fast backups or quick restores? Depending on these answers you can decide if incremental backups are a benefit.